# In storyboard, embedded view controllers no longer same size as their container views

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uistoryboard, uicontainerview

I have a storyboard with multiple view controllers, several of which have container views with embedded view controllers. Until recently, the embedded view controllers correctly sized themselves in the storyboard based on the size of their container views. But now they all show at 600 x 600 (which is not the size of any of the containers). They do assume the proper sizes when I run the app.

Is there a way to restore the default behavior in the storyboard? (And what might have caused this?) (XCode 7.2)

Comment: May I ask why you care? The actual size will be determined at runtime, and the positions and sizes of the subviews will be determined by their constraints. If you're doing a good job of designing, you should not be dependent on the view being shown at _any_ particular size - which is exactly what the "neutral" 600x600 shape is intended to suggest.

Comment: (1) It results in a slew of compiler warnings about frame sizes being different at run time, masking actual cases we might be concerned about; (2) The layouts are complex and its faster to work with them if the relative sizes and positions of the embedded controllers are correctly reflected in the storyboard; (3) This is not the default behavior Apple intended and I'd like to know what might have caused it.

Comment: "its faster to work with them if the relative sizes and positions of the embedded controllers are correctly reflected in the storyboard" Well, all you have to do is switch to Freeform and you can have any container size you want.

Comment: The containers are all sized correctly and all auto-layout constraints are working. The problem is that the view controllers embedded in them are not the size of their containers. The embedded view controllers (showing off to the side linked by their embed segues) should be assuming the size of the containers automatically (that is the default storyboard behavior) but they've suddenly stopped doing that.

Comment: I understand that. I don't know why that happened; if I did, I'd be answering. I'm not answering. I'm commenting. And in my comments I'm suggesting workarounds. One might be not to worry about it. Another might be to size the view controller yourself, and I've told you how to do that. Either (or both) of these suggestions would at least permit you to get on with life, as it were.

Comment: Thanks, Matt. If all else fails I'll resize manually, but I'm trying to avoid that because then, if I resize the containers again in the future, I'll have to manually resize the embedded view controllers manually again... and there are a LOT of them in this layout. Appreciate the comments, though. I've just never seen this happen and would like to understand what's up.

Comment: I've never seen it either (or heard of it). If switching to a different size and then back to Inferred doesn't fix it, I would suggest submitting a bug report to Apple. This is not supposed to happen.

Answer (score 1):

In the **Simulated Metrics** section of the size inspector change the *Size* from **Inferred** to **Detail**:

[image]

New:

[[image: S[2]]

Answer (score 0):

Change the ViewController/Navigation Controller attribute in `'Simulated Metrics' from Inferred to 'Page Sheet' or 'Form Sheet'` to get a full size storyboard. This removes the shrinking effect